# Как избавиться от двойного запроса данных контроллером?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-routing

Шаблон грузится динамически роутером, а скрипт контроллера подключается гвоздями в html (надеюсь, что все таки можно [грузить и его динамически)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428249/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
app.controller('MapCtr', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$log',
    function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $log) {
        angular.extend($rootScope, {
            dataForGlobal: []
        });

        angular.extend($scope, {
            dataForLocal: [],
            waypoints: {},
            tracks: {},
            defaults: {
               zoomControlPosition: 'bottomright'
            }
        });

        $http.get('api/v1/fignya')
            .success( function(fignya) {
                    $rootScope.dataForGlobal = fignya.global;
                    $scope.dataForLocal = fignya.local;
                })
            .error( function(fignya) {
                    console.warn('Error: ' + fignya);
                });
    }]
);
```

По какой-то причине запрос `api/v1/fignya` выполняется два раза подряд.
При этом если делать этот же запрос в `MainCtr` (закрепленным за `body`), то он выполняется однократно.

Как решить проблему двойного запроса данных контролером шаблона?

**Update**:

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtr">
    <leaflet width="100%" height="100%" markers="markers" paths="tracks" defaults="defaults"></leaflet>
</div>
```

Это шаблон который грузится роутером ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428249/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)).
Контроллер подключается в index.html (пока не сделал динамическую загрузку).

Роутер используется так:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="./lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtr">
    ...
    <div class="containerView">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <script src="./app/baseCtrls.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что вы используете директиву ng-controller, и роутер одновременно. Покажите, как вы подключаете контроллер ко view.

Comment: Вы были правы - дублирование контрола в роутере и внутри шаблона приводило к такому эффекту, спасибо.  Ответьте пожалуйста - я закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы используете директиву ng-controller, и роутер одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

У вас ng-view используется в глобальном контексте. Это само по себе неплохо до тех пор, пока на подтянется еще какая-то вьюха с такой же директивой.
Проверьте, ng-view без указания имени должен быть один на странице, остальные должны быть проименованы.

Answer (score 2):

Если контроллер прибивается роутером, в шаблоне не надо писать ng-controller. Из-за того контроллер два раза работает, я думаю

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?